# How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, binary-variable

Suppose we have a binary variable $x$ and a non-negative continuous variable $y$.  How can we linearize the product $x y$?

Comment: To generate more expected content for our new OR forum and since it is allowed to answers your own questions: I added this basic OR questions. see: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I think it's a good idea to have a question dedicated to this type of questions (how to linearize X * Y where ...). On OR-X, we have lots of questions dedicated to the linearization of products or division. This question could be a reference point for future similar questions. If you agree, we could make this a Wiki question and the community develop it over time.

Comment: Related: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/should-basic-questions-be-made-community-wikis

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Suppose we can give a finite upper bound for $y$ called $M$. Then this constraint can easily be linearized by using the so-called big $M$ method. We introduce a new variable $z$ that should take the same value as the product $x y$.

Notice that the product which we model by $z$ equals zero if $x = 0$ but $z$ can take any value between $0$ and $M$ if $x = 1$. We can model this by using $z \leq x M$. Next, the product is always non-negative and smaller than $y$, thus $z\geq 0$ and $z \leq y$.

It is left to force $z$ to equal $y$ in case $x = 1$ which we obtain with
$$ z \geq y - (1 - x)M. $$

Comment: If M is 10. At x=0: z>=y-M.  y can be any number between 0 and 10. If y =1: z>1-10, then z>-9; z is not necessarily equal to zero contrary to what you stated. Can you please explain more?

Answer (score -1):

The four required constraints are summarized below for **non-negative** case:

$z<=M.x$          (1)

$z<=y$            (2)

$z>=y-(1-x).M$    (3)

$z>=0$            (4)

For **negative and nonnegative**, the general formula is give here: https://www.fico.com/en/resource-access/download/3217   (page 7, section 2.8)

Comment: These are the same four constraints as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks@ RobPratt! I am not sure, but I guess the one found on page 7 of the Ref below is better: https://www.fico.com/en/resource-access/download/3217   (Section 2.8)

Comment: That one is a generalization.  If you take $L=0$ (because $y$ in this question is nonnegative), you arrive at the same four constraints.