# McCormick envelopes and nonlinear constraints

Tags: linearization, nonlinear-programming, mccormick

I have a problem with a nonlinear constraint. The non-linearity stems from a term of the form $xb$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $x < M$ and $b \in \{0, 1\}$. I am able to remove this non-linearity by using McCormick envelopes.

If I solve the problem using this relaxation, am I actually solving the problem or am I just finding a very tight lower bound?. Remember that one of the variables is binary.

What if $b \in \mathbb{N}$ instead?

Comment: `lower bound' -- what is your objective sense, how does the constraint look like

Comment: [Possibly related question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/39/358)

Answer (score 11):

For real $x\in[l,u]$ and binary $b\in\{0,1\}$ the McCormick envelope gives you bounds on $w=xy$

$$\begin{align}
lb & \leq w \leq ub,\\
ub+x-u& \leq w\leq x+lb-l.
\end{align}$$

By case analysis you can see that this is equal to $w=xb$, so you will indeed solve the problem.