# How to linearize a product of an integer and a binary variable

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, linearization

i have this constraint right here, which is not linear. How would i linearize such a product. $number_t$ is a positive integer and $new_t$ and $reset_t$ are binary.

$$number_t = (number_{t-1}+new_t)\cdot (1-reset_t)$$

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-to-linearize-the-multiplication-of-an-integer-and-a-binary-integer-variable?rq=1

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to linearize the multiplication of an integer and a binary integer variable?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-to-linearize-the-multiplication-of-an-integer-and-a-binary-integer-variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments already hinted at questions that give you the answer. In your specific example, this translates to the following:

\begin{align}
0 \leq number_t \leq (number_{t−1}+new_t) \newline
number_t \geq (number_{t−1}+new_t)-reset_tM \newline
number_t \leq M(1−reset_t)
\end{align}

If $reset_t = 0$, through the first and second constraint we force $number_t$ to take value $number_{t-1}+new_t$. If $reset_t=1$, through the first and third constraint, we force $number_t$ to be 0. Where $M$ is a large enough number.

Comment: Thank you @PeterD. Assuming i also have $number_t = (number_{t-1}+new_t)\cdot (1-reset_t)-c_t + b_t$, which of both are also binary, how would i need to modify the constraints then? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Would it work if, for example, I replace $number_t$ with $nr_t$ in your solution and then calculate $number_t=nr_t-c_t+b_t$?

Comment: @Uniewr yes that would work.