# Can we simplify (perhaps linearize) this constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, nonlinear-programming, stochastic-programming

We are dealing with a stochastic model and one of the constraints is
\begin{align}
y_j=\frac{\sum_{i \in I}\sum_{k \in K}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{ik}^2\right]x^k_{ij}}{\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{k \in K} \mathbb{E}\left[X_{ik}\right]x^k_{ij}}.
\end{align}
Here, decision variables are $y_j\geq 0$ and $x_{ij}^k$ which is binary and $X_{ik}$ is a random variable for which we know its mean and variance.

Is there a way to perhaps linearize this constraint? The only thing that came to mind for me was to use ${Var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2$, but this was not useful.

I would appreciate some hints so I try to solve it myself.

Comment: Do you also have constraints like $\sum_i x_{ij}^k=1$ or maybe $\sum_k x_{ij}^k=1$?

Comment: We have $\sum_j \sum_k x_{ij}^k=1$ for all $i$. Could you please let me know why this important? Is there another way to simplify the ratio?

Comment: I was thinking that you might be able to apply *compact linearization* a la Liberti.  Where else does $y_j$ appear in the model?

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking it up now. The complete constraint that we modeled is $\mathbb{E}[Y_j]=(y_j z_j)/(1-z_j)$ for all $j$ and $z_j>0$, and we have $y_j$ as mentioned in the question. That is why I was trying to linearize the $RHS$ of $y_j$ by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the denominator cannot be zero (which would cause the known universe to implode) and that you can provide an upper bound for $y_j$, you can multiply both sides of the equation by the denominator. The new right side (the numerator) will be linear. The new left side will be $\sum_i \sum_k \mu_{ik} x_{ij}^k y_j$ (where $\mu$ is the mean of $X$). Now you just need to linearize the product $x_{ij}^k y_j$, which is a FAQ. See [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable) for an answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to simplify the LHS by itself?

Comment: @prubin, Thanks for your useful answer. could you say please, how the new RHS might be linear if $\mathbb{E} X^2_{i,k}$ would be a variable? Is it replaced by its mean that is a parameter?

Comment: @A.Omidi $X_{i,k}$ is a random variable, not a decision (model) variable. As noted by the author, the expectation of the square is the sum of the variance and the square of the mean, both of which I am assuming are parameters to the problem.

Comment: @ZiggyIggy I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @prubin, Many thanks for your explanation.