# Can we linearize the division of a binary variable by a continuous variable?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, reformulation-linearization

I'm trying to solve an MINLP problem where the following division term is appearing in the objective:
$$z_r = \frac{x_{ry}}{\sum_r d_r x_{ry}}, \forall r, y,$$ where $x_{ry}$ is a 2D binary variable and $d_r$ is a non-zero real number. In addition, there is a constraint $\sum_r x_{ry} \leq 1$. Is there a suitable way to linearize this division?

I tried to use a new variable $M_r = z_r \times \sum_r d_r x_{ry}$, but the situation is still the same for the commercial solvers.

Comment: I think your idea with $M_r$ is good. You can now linearize $z_r \times x_{ry}$ like this : https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable

Comment: You are using $r$ in two different ways in the same constraint: $\forall r$ and $\sum_r$

Comment: Agree. Instead, we can use $x_y = \sum_r d_r x_{ry}$, but the problem is still the same, i.e., $z_r = \frac{x_{ry}}{x_y}, \forall r,y$.

Comment: And your $\le 1$ constraint must be $=1$ to avoid division by zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to linearize
\begin{align}
z_r &= \frac{x_{ry}}{\sum_s d_s x_{sy}} &&\text{for all $r$ and $y$} \tag1 \\
\sum_s x_{sy} &= 1 &&\text{for all $y$} \tag2
\end{align}

- If $x_{ry}=0$, then $(1)$ implies that $z_r=0$.
- If $x_{ry}=1$, then $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that $z_r=1/d_r$.

So you can linearize $(1)$ by replacing it with
$$z_r=x_{ry}/d_r \quad \text{for all $r$ and $y$} \tag3$$

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. Would you say please, is there any preference to linearize such division by conic reformulation, specifically, SOCP than other methods like what you mentioned?

Comment: I would be very surprised if there is a better reformulation than what I proposed in my answer, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Glad to help.  Notice that $x_{ry}=d_r z_r$, so it doesn't depend on $y$.  Is that expected in your problem?  If so, probably better to just drop the $y$ index: $x_r$.

Comment: No, $y$ is needed. Basically, $x_{ry}$ indicates if $r$ is associated with $y$, like in an assignment problem. However, now I'm seeing a small problem with the denominator being replaced with $d_r$. The sum indicates the total $d_r$ of all the $r$'s associated with $y$, which we do not know beforehand.

Comment: If the numerator is $0$, the (nonzero) denominator doesn’t matter. If the numerator is $1$, the denominator must be $d_r$.