# How to linearize a product and ratio of $x$ and $y$ where $x$ is binary and $y$ is a continuous variable?

Tags: linearization, binary-variable

I am an electrical engineer who is currently learning about optimization. From this [post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables), they have shown how to linearize the product of two binary variables.

But in my case, I have a product $x \times y$ and a ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ where $x$ is binary and $y$ is a continuous non negative variable. Therefore, my question is how to linearize them ?

Would you kindly help me with this problem ?

Thank you very much for your enthusiasm !

Comment: For the first this [link](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/39/199) and for the second this [link](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/7873/199) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Tuong. Not sure this is what you're looking for, but maybe this paper might help: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2581394?seq=2