# Correct way to set a quadratic constraint Xpress

Tags: linear-programming, python, minimax

I'm implementing on Xpress a problem with different solution proposed on a paper. The idea is to decompose a matrix $X$ into a convex sum $\sum_{t}\lambda_t M^{(t)}$, where each $M^{(t)}$ has only either $0$ or $1$, better stated we have that $M^{(t)} = (m^{(t)}_{ij})_{ij}$ and each $m_{ij}$ is a binary variable. In order to find such decomposition, we consider another continuous variable $\alpha$ and resolve the problem:

$$\begin{align}
&\min\; \alpha \tag{1}\\ 
&\text{s.t.}\\
&\sum_{t}\lambda_t = 1 \tag{2}\\
&\sum_{j} m^{(t)}_{ij}\leq 1 \quad \forall i\;\forall t \tag{3}\\
&\sum_{i}m^{(t)}_{ij}\leq q_{i} \quad \forall j\;\forall t \tag{4}\\
&\sum_{t}\lambda_t M^{(t)} - X \geq 0 \tag{5}\\
&\sum_{t}\lambda_t M^{(t)} - X \leq \alpha\tag{6}\\
&\lambda_t,\alpha\geq 0
\end{align}$$

Equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ are problematic because they are quadratic and would yield a non convex region. We can linearize it by introducing a variable $z^{(t)}_{ij}=\lambda_{t}m^{(t)}_{ij}$ where $Z^{(t)} = (z^{(t)}_{ij})_{ij}$ which ultimately changes the equations to: $$\sum_t Z^{(t)} - X \geq 0\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{t}Z^{(t)} - X \leq\alpha$$
which is now linear but requires the additional constraints:
$$\forall i, j,t\hspace{2mm}: 0\leq z_{ij}^{(t)}\leq \lambda_t \qquad z_{ij}^{(t)}\geq \lambda_t + m_{ij}^{(t)}-1$$
The code runs perfectly with a non trivial output, meaning that the problem is feasible. Nontheless the new solution looses the meaning of the initial implementetion: the non linearized equation would have given as a result, $0-1$ matrixes, which is my aim actually. By linearizing, the solution looses any interpretation (as the $z$'s need now to be continuous variables). What's the best idea to set back now? Is dividing each $Z^{(t)}$ by its $\lambda_t$ and rounding the numbers a meaningful step?

Comment: Is $\lambda_t$ a nonnegative variable? Is $q_i$ a constant?

Comment: What is the relationship between $m_{ij}$ and $M^{(t)}$?

Comment: @prubin I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @RobPratt the $\lambda_t$ are coefficients of a convex combination, so by definition they are nonnegative. The $q_i$, as well as $X$, are constants given by the problem.

Comment: The reason this is not allowed is that Xpress only supports convex MIQCPs. Any nonlinear equality constraint makes the problem immediately non-convex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you with Xpress, but one approach is to linearize the problem by replacing the products $\lambda_t m_{ij}^{(t)}$ with new nonnegative variables $z_{ijt}$, together with constraints that enforce the product.  See [How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable)

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Indeed I did not know about such trick but it introduces a new challenge. How do we get back to binary matrixes?

Comment: @DavideTrono You should still impose that $m_{ij}^{(t)}$ is binary.

Comment: $m^{(t)}_{ij}$ is binary, the $z^{(t)}_{ij}$ I thought should be the same type as the $\lambda$'s. This is so because otherwise the output is: $\lambda_0=1$ (with all the remanings equal to 0) and $Z^{(0)}$ being $1$ where $X$ is non zero. Arguably okay result.

Comment: Yes, $z$ is the same type (nonnegative continuous) as $\lambda$.  Your linearization is missing $z_{ij}^{(t)} \le m_{ij}^{(t)}$.

Comment: I thought that it was redundant because $m_{ij}^{(t)} = 0$ or 1 and since $\lambda_t\leq1$ then $z_{ij}^{(t)}\leq\lambda_t$ was already enough.

Comment: Without the missing constraint, you are not enforcing the implication $m_{ij}^{(t)} = 0 \implies z_{ij}^{(t)} = 0$.