# using milp for a linear complementarity problem

Tags: optimization, modeling, linearization, nonconvex-programming

I have to minimize $c^Tx$
subject to  $Ax = b$, $x_iw_i = 0$ for all $i$, with $x$ non negative continuous and $w$ binary.
What model should I use to solve this problem?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable

Comment: @Kuifje That reformulation is correct but overkill for this special case where you want the product to be $0$.  In particular, no new variable is needed,

Comment: yes indeed, I agree. Shall I remove the comment to avoid confusion?

Comment: Still useful to have the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Equivalently, you want to enforce $$w_i=1\implies x_i\le 0.$$ You can either use an indicator constraint to express this directly or use the following big-M constraint:
$$x_i \le M_i(1-w_i),$$
where $M_i$ is a (small) constant upper bound on $x_i$.