# How to linearize the product of a binary and a negative continuous variable?

Tags: linearization, binary-variable

Suppose we have a binary variable $x$ and a negative continuous variable $y$. How can we linearize the product $u=xy$?

Comment: You can define $z=-y$ and use the usual technique described for example [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

replace the constraint with the followings where $M$ is a large number:

$u \le(1-x)M +y$

$u \ge(1-x)M +y$

$u \le xM$

$u \ge -xM$

Comment: thanks a lot,  I think the third and fourth constraints are not correct for example for x=1 & y=-5 we can't get u=-5.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

base on use the usual technique described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable?rq=1) and general formula is give [here](https://www.fico.com/en/resource-access/download/3217)(page 7, section 2.8) we get to this:

\begin{array}{ll}
\ u = x.y \\
u\le 0\\
u\ge -Mx\\
u\ge y\\
u\le y+M(1-x)
\end{array}